# How to fetch catalog Product in UiComponent in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to fetch Catalog product in custom UiComponent.I am trying to fetch Productdata by existing collectionfactory .But data is not fetched. I am using the DataProvider is **Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection**  and the CollectionFactory is **Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Grid\Collection** . Here is my di.xml

```
<virtualType name="AllexistproductGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allproductexist_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type> 
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">catalog_category_product</argument>           
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

As you can see, I think i am using the wrong DataProvider and CollectionFactory. I can't understand which DataProvider and CollectionFactory i have to use to fetch existing catalog product. Please help.